# Determining runtime complexity

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

I'm trying to determine the runtime complexity of an algorithm that I have written to take an array and determine the length of the longest continuous subsequence of the array where the difference in the max and min of the subsequence is less than or equal to some given value.

The code

```
input = [16,19,20,22,27,23]
compareValue = 3
tmp,length = 0,0
for i in range(0,n):
  newArray = []
  for j in range(i,n):
      newArray.append(input[j])
      if abs(max(newArray) - min(newArray)) <= compareValue:
          tmp = len(newArray)
      else:
           if tmp > length
               length = tmp
```

the output from this this example would be 3

I've tried determining this on my own by reading examples on Big-O, but I'm not 100% certain as to the exact complexity and would really appreciate some clarification.

Edit: From what've read I think this runs in O(n^2), but again, I am not completely sure

Comment: So what have you figured out so far?

Comment: @JoelCornett added an edit of what I think it's running in based off what I've read.

Comment: and I think it's 42. We need your explanation, not a final result.

Comment: hint: calculate the number of iterations + you have to know the complexity of used operations (eg: len, max...)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: it's always 42 ;)

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 loops. Suppose that number of elements is 5. Second loop iterations will be decreasing by 1 on each parent loop iteration:

outer loop iteration : `* * * * *`
inner loop iterations: `5 4 3 2 1`

By summing second (or inner) loop iterations you can calculate overall number of 'operations' or complexity. And you have here simple **summ of natural numbers from 1 to n** (5). And formula for that summ is:

`n * (n + 1) / 2` or `(n^2 + n) / 2`

at last in your inner loop on every iteration you are adding element to `newArray` and calling `min` and `max` on it. Complexity of both `min` and `max` is O(n) but length of array decreasing:

min,max for j in 0-4: `2 * (O(1)+O(2)+...+O(5))`
min,max for j in 0-3: `2 * (O(1)+O(2)+...+O(4))`
min,max for j in 0-2: `2 * (O(1)+O(2)+...+O(3))`
min,max for j in 0-1: `2 * (O(1)+O(2)+...+O(2))`
min,max for j in 0  : `2 * O(1)`

and overall complexity will be summ: `O(n^2 + n) + O((n-1)^2 + (n-1)) + ... O(1)`

I think that roughly complexity of both min+max is `O(2*n/2)` or just `O(n)`, so overall will be:

`(n^2 + n) / 2 * (n)` or `(n^3 + n^2) / 2`

or `O(n^3)`

Comment: complexity analysis is more complex than just checking the *loops*.

Comment: "Where in my answer i say that comlexity analisis is not complex :)" - how could you (intentionally?) misinterpret a simple sentence like this? "more complex than just checking the loops" - this is a whole expression, don't ignore half of it.....  I see you saw 42. This means you read the comments, where I explain what else you have to check.

Comment: it's an *essential* part of big oh analysis and it's relevant here. you're assuming all the operations are O(1). If some googling doesn't convince you, feel free to post a question about this.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath mm, i think i see what you mean now... im noticed min and max right now :) You should say about it. Im sorry, lets clear this comments, i will edit my anser

Comment: Sorry, that's style. You learn more if you figure out things yourself, so I prefer to give only hints.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath plz check now, and edit your answer to make me able to remove - on it

Comment: "Complexity of both min and max is O(log(n)" - with some data structures: yes... with a plain array: no.